# Confirm before quit thunar file manager

Tags: xfce, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

Thunar support [user custom action](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions). But is this possible to add something like 'Confirm before quit'.

Because I saw CUA examples mentioned doesn't change thunar behavior it self. But 'adding' more capabilities to thunar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question though I'm not sure you can do it via custom actions.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible without editing source-code and compiling yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use zenity and xdotool to emulate the behaviour via Thunar Custom Action. With the help of command line tools, no need to look at source code for such capability.

### How it works

First, use zenity to display GTK+ dialog box with custom text "Confirm to quit Thunar?" using the question format. When either button (OK or Cancel) is pressed, zenity will return an exit value (0 or 1).

A zero indicates success and a nonzero value indicates failure. Therefore, when the OK button is pressed, that will return exit value `0` and parsing to logical AND `&&` will continue to run the following command.

The following command will use xdotool to emulate key press to quit Thunar, which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, via command line. The final result is same as the user pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> directly from the keyboard.

### How to setup

Follow the steps to create the custom action in Thunar.

1. Open Terminal and install the required programs via APT, or install from the package manager of choice.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install zenity xdotool
   ```
2. Open Thunar file manager, and go to **Edit > Configure custom actions...** to open the Custom Actions window.
3. In the Custom Actions window, click on **"plus"** in the list of buttons (the one labeled with a "+"), and a dialog with two tabs will appear.
4. Under **Basic** tab, fill in the details in corresponding fields.

   > Name: **Quit after confirm**
   >
   > Description: (optional)
   >
   > Command: **zenity --question --title="Thunar Custom Actions" --text="Confirm to quit Thunar?" && xdotool key ctrl+q**
   >
   > Icon: (optional)

   To select the same icon used for "Close Window" menu in Thunar, click on **No icon** button and search for "system-shutdown", select the icon and click **OK**. The icon will be selected.
5. Under **Appearance Conditions** tab, look for "Appears if selection contains:" and **fill in the checkbox** for "Directories".
6. Click **OK** to close the dialog.
7. Finally, click **Close** to finish.

### How to use

Open Thunar file manager, and browse any directory. Right-click on mouse and select "Quit after confirm" (or whatever name given in step 4) in the context menu. That will display a dialog with the specified details.

[image: Thunar Custom Action with zenity and xdotool]

Click **No** will do nothing.

Click **Yes** will run emulated combination key press that will close the *current window* of Thunar.

If the user wish to close *all window* and not just current window of Thunar, change the key combination in step 4 from `ctrl+q` to `ctrl+shift+w` instead. That is all.

Comment: I use both zenity and xdotool in my toy projects. Thank you for the answer. But it doesn't work using <kbd>ctrl+q</kbd> directly in my machine (i3wm). Also I still can close it directly using <kbd>Super+Shift+Q</kbd> (Kill Focused window). Firefox/Okular/etc in other hand trigger confirmation even I close with either first or second way,

Comment: To close windows in Thunar, the shortcut key is ctrl+q at least for Xfce DE. According to [i3wm docs](https://i3wm.org/docs/3.e/userguide.html#_closing_windows), application shortcut is respected first. If ctrl+q didn't work, change to whatever that works for you. I don't think I can help beyond that.

Comment: Great if it's working under Xfce DE. Yes, I tried `ctrl+q` but it doesn't work. Now I heavily hack my dired and use it  as my daily file manager.